# How to make custom component selectable via :checked pseudo-class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, css-selectors

I have a custom Angular 2+ toggle/switch component that has a hidden checkbox to control its state.

CSS has had [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo-class selector for ages, and it's pretty convenient when you need to style siblings based on the state of the checkbox, without ever having to resort to JS trickery:

```css
#chk:not(:checked) ~ .party {
  display: none;
}

#chk:checked ~ .sleepy {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="chk" type="checkbox"/> ⬅ ☕☕☕
<h1 class="sleepy"></h1>
<h1 class="party">✨</h1>
```

What I would *really* like to know is how (or whether) I can make my custom switch, when flipped to `true`, trigger the pseudo-class just like a checkbox would - i.e.: picture the above snippet with a hypothetical `<app-custom-switch>` element instead of a regular checkbox.

I know I *could* dynamically add classes to my component and use them instead of the pseudo-class, but I want to know if we can trick the CSS selectors to treat our component as a checkbox and use its `value` or `checked` attributes to trigger the abovementioned pseudo-class.

I tried adding a `checked` attribute to it programmatically, but nope - doesn't work.

Please feel free to add your remarks on whether you think what I'm trying to achieve is good practice at all. For now, I just want to know if that's achievable, and if so, how.

Comment: you should extends from [ControlValueAccesor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). There're a lot of examples in web

Comment: @NarenMurali I know I can, and I also know I can use classes that, to me, would make a little more sense than attributes in this case. However, as I stated, I want to know if there are any ways to treat my component as a regular checkbox. I simply want to know if the inner workings of CSS selectors allow me to mimic this behavior.

Comment: @Eliseo I am already implementing (not extending, since it's an interface) `ControlValueAccessor`. There's even a class (not an interface) called `CheckboxControlValueAccessor`, which I did try extending and passing down `Renderer2` and `ElementRef`. Did you test it? Neither works. You're welcome to post this as an answer if you have a working example, but I think the question also begs an explanation on _why_ it works.

Comment: You could go with the pseudo class AND a custom classs with something like `:is(:checked, .checked)`